# Apply colors to a cell based on text in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I don’t want to use conditional formatting because I need a different value as the text in the cell (not what the color values apply to).

Column E is status (at risk/on track/needs improvement)
Column I is trend, displayed as arrows (Unicode text)
Column J is blank

I would like the color of the corresponding cells to be based on Column E text “Needs Improvement” in red, “At Risk” in yellow, and “On Track” in green.

In J2 through J13, I need the color only from the E2:E13 status and the trend arrows from I2:I13.

This has been asked before in one way or another, but I can’t figure out the conditional formatting in VBA.

Conditional formatting doesn’t work, I tried to pull conditional colors from column E, but the code couldn’t integrate conditional formatting colors (it had to be true cell colors).

Comment: What you describe is exactly what conditional formatting is for. Can you show us the conditional formatting you tried?

Comment: I find USUALLY conditional formatting is going to be significantly easier and more reliable... also faster... than a VBA formatting option. I'll post an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the 4 sets of conditional formatting I used to accomplish the below example. I did not know what your trend data looks like so you'll need to adjust that to fit. To note, the formula in column J is ["=I" & row], so it's pulling over the same values. Those are hidden with the icon formatting. ::

**Where RG = range("J2:J18")**

```
Colour:="Red"     while [=$E2="At Risk"] 
Colour:="Yellow"  while [=$E2="Needs Improvement"]
Colour:="Green"   while [=$E2="On Track"] 
Shape:="Icon Set" [checkmark] Show Icon Only
```

Example of formatting:
[image]

Example of result:
[image]

Let me know if any of that doesn't make sense.

Comment: oh okay thank you, I feel like this was the first thing I tried and somehow it makes more sense when you do it. I appreciate it

Comment: There are a couple little pieces to keep in mind. like the fact that the formulas need to be "$E2", not "$E$2" or "E$2" or "E2". And the fact that the icons cannot look at other cells; that's why we need J column to = I column